# seemed to leave or seemed to have left?

Tags: to-infinitive, perfect-aspect

What is the difference between the uses of tense and aspect in the following sentences? I was told that the use of the perfect infinitive indicates an event which occurred prior to the "seeming" event.

> a. The accident seemed to leave 50 people dead and many others injured.

> b. The accident seemed to have left 50 people dead and many others injured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of "seem to be" is about making a judgement about something. "He seems to be happy" means "I think he is happy, based on my judgement of his appearance".

The difference between "seemed to be" and "seemed to have been" is whether this is the judgement made at the time, or with hindsight. Whether, it seemed *at the time of the accident (or shortly after)* that there were 50 people dead, or whether it seemed *when considering the accident later*, that 50 people were dead.  If the accident was recent, then there might not have been time for reflection. The first sentence reads more like a news report, the second like an historical report.

A common inference from the use of "seem" is that the judgement is incorrect.  "He seems happy (but in fact he is upset)."  So another difference is how quickly it was discovered that the judgement was incorrect.  Was it immediately clear that the death toll was different, or was it only much later?

The actual example is rather odd and gruesome. And the difference is minor.

Comment: In a news report, wouldn't it be more likely to say, "The accident **seems to have left** 50 people dead and many others injured"?